# How to join 2 mm stainless steel welding rods without a TIG welder

Tags: structural-engineering, welding

I have to build an [egg tray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vw-QKToDMVY). The material used for such trays is 2 mm stainless steel welding rods.

When I queried nearby workshops they said a TIG welder is needed to weld such material and it is very difficult to weld such thin rods: they bend or lose temper. I don't have a TIG welder. Is there a cost-effective and simple way to do this?

I also found [an article about soldering stainless steel](http://www.bssa.org.uk/topics.php?article=150). I have a soldering iron. Can stainless steel be soldered with the soldering iron used for circuit soldering? What type of flux and lead would I need? Will it produce an effective and permanent bond?

Answer (score 3):

I think brazing would be correct for your application. Unless, the entire tray system needs to be stainless steel for hygienic and/or anti-corrosive reasons. Brazing is like soldering, you likely may be able to find a smaller handheld torch and the correct brazing rod for less than the cost of a TIG welding service. Also, it will require some skill and practice to get it right.

Also, depending on your budget, you may want to look into a spot welder. That might do the trick for you. Or, speak with a sheet metal fabrication shop and ask them if they can spot weld your trays.